# Spring Webclient retry and execute a code if all retries are exhausted

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a webhook service that sends events to different sources (URLs). By design, the request timeout is 10s, if it fails, retries to send 3 times. In case, all retries are failed, a code must be executed to disable that URL in DB.

So far, I managed to retry and with delay of 5 seconds. But, I'm not sure how to execute code after failure.

```
    try{

          String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(webhookDTO);

                webClient.post()
                        .uri(webhook.getUrl())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(body)
                        .exchange()
                        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                                .jitter(0d)
                                .doAfterRetry(retrySignal -> {
                                    logger.info("Retried " + retrySignal.totalRetries());
                                })
                                .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) 
                                                    -> new WebhookTimeoutException()))
                        .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> {
                            logger.info("Event is received by " + client);
                        })
                        .subscribe();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error on webhook dispatcher: ", e);
            }
```

Can anyone give some examples of how to do this?

Comment: Please avoid using try-catch as much as possible while using Reactor.

Comment: @PrashantPandey Thanks for suggestion. why do you think so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there! Just use `doOnError` as shown here. The idea here, once after all the attempts failed, you throw `WebhookTimeoutException`. The doOnError is called only when the error is thrown & updates the DB. The exception class is optional. You can ignore that.

```
webClient.post()
        .uri(webhook.getUrl())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bodyValue(body)
        .exchange()
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .jitter(0d)
                .doAfterRetry(retrySignal -> {
                    logger.info("Retried " + retrySignal.totalRetries());
                })
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) 
                                    -> new WebhookTimeoutException()))
        .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> {
            logger.info("Event is received by " + client);
        })
        .doOnError(WebhookTimeoutException.class, (msg) -> {
            System.out.println("Message :: " + msg);
            // here update the DB
            dbRepository.save(...);
        })        
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Wow. It worked. cheers. I tried `doOnError` but before `retryWhen()`. I didn't know there is a difference :)

Comment: note this uses the `RetrySpec`, newly introduced in reactor-core 3.3.4.RELEASE (which allows to use a specific exception class for retry exhausted case, even possibly a custom one)